# Java, date from separate JSON values to string to date

Tags: java, sql, json, date, simpledateformat

I have a JSON object being returned to my app that contains a date

```
date": {
"year": 2011,
"month": 5,
"dayOfMonth": 30,
"hourOfDay": 16,
"minute": 13,
"second": 47
},
```

I need to use this date and store it in a SQL database, most likely as a string, so I parse this date object using the JSON functions in Java

Here I am trying to format the whole section as a string with dashes between the date and colons between the hours minutes seconds. Hoping that I could parse it with SimpleDateFormat, but that fails with parserexceptionerror

```
dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject").getString("year") + "-" +
dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject").getString("month") + "-" +
dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject").getString("dayOfMonth") + " " +
dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject").getString("hourOfDay") + ":" +
dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject").getString("minute") + ":" +
dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject").getString("second");
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

I need to take the JSON strings and combine them into a readable date which ideally I can turn into a string. This can be a formatted date - such as something `simpledateformat` will do, or it can be in milliseconds.

Insight Appreciated

Comment: I'm sure a date format could be specified to convert from a String, built from different parts of the incoming JSON, into a java.util.Date instance.  What date format pattern did you try?

Comment: Note that in the JSON processing example, the repetitious dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject") calls could be replaced with JSONObject dateJson = dataObj.getJSONObject("dateObject"); dateJson.getString("year") + "-" + etc.  This would have performance improvements, which might not matter.  It also helps the code to be more maintainable, since any small associated change wouldn't need be made six times, but just one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the goal is to transform a String representation of date information, formatted for example as "2011-5-30 16:13:47", into a `java.util.Date` instance...

```
String dateString = "2011-5-30 16:13:47";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateString);
System.out.println(date);
// output: Mon May 30 16:13:47 MST 2011

String dateString2 = "2011-11-3 16:13:47";
Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateString2);
System.out.println(date2);
// output: Thu Nov 03 16:13:47 MST 2011
```

An alternative would be to turn all of the JSON input values into Java ints, and then use `Calendar.getInstance().set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec).getTime()`.

Comment: this worked for me, very flexible. I was using the wrong "SimpleDateFormat" seed. I fixed the format to your `"yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss"` which you probably got from looking at my string, and I stopped getting parser exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already, you should take a look at JSON libraries that make json serialization and deserialization much easier. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and Google's [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) are both excellent.

A JSON library knows how to read a date JSON string into a `java.util.Date` object. You can then store it in your database in a datetime column. The advantage of storing dates as proper datetime data types in databases is that you can build queries much easier- for example if you need to select all records between two dates. If that was a string column, your query will quickly get ugly. The other thing about datetime is that it's stored in a fixed length column (stores the milli second long values in many database implementations), so storage is efficient. Storing as a string can easily take more space if you start counting all the characters in a full SimpleDateFormat-ed string. As a result of that, building an index on a datetime becomes more efficient that building it on a varied-length string column.

Comment: Informative, but is my JSON Object titled `date` already in a format that the JSON functions can read as a date object? I am currently subject to how this object is returned to me

Comment: The JSON you posted is not in any standard Date format. You may have to create your own Model Object, MyDate, that has the fields year, day, month, ...etc on it. GSON will then be able to turn your JSON string into an instance of that object. Your model object can then have a convenience method on it that builds a java Calendar/Date object out of its fields to make your life a bit easier.

Comment: There's nothing in Gson or Jackson or any other JSON processing API I've seen to make the conversion to java.util.Date significantly easier.  Such APIs just make it more convenient to serialize/deserialize Java to/from JSON.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Turning Date into JSON and back into Date is supported out of the box in GSON. One has the option to choose between different date formats as well- see the GsonBuilder settings for date: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html . The problem here is that the date is not represented in the JSON in any standard format.